How to Stop Google Cloud Ops Agent from Logging syslog Entries?
I've been trying to configure the Google Cloud Ops Agent (formerly known as Stackdriver Logging) to stop collecting syslog entries on my Ubuntu server, but despite several attempts, it continues to log these entries.
Here is what I have tried so far:
Checked and updated the Google Cloud Ops Agent configuration:
My current configuration only specifies log files from Nginx and my Laravel application:
logging:   receivers:
    nginx_error:
      type: files
      include_paths:
        - /var/log/nginx/error.log
    app_worker:
      type: files
      include_paths:
        - /var/www/html/site/storage/logs/worker.log
    app_laravel:
      type: files
      include_paths:
        - /var/www/html/site/storage/logs/laravel.log

  service:
    pipelines:
      nginx_pipeline:
        receivers:
          - nginx_error
      application_pipeline:
        receivers:
          - app_worker
          - app_laravel

Ensured that there are no syslog references in the configuration files:
I have checked /etc/google-cloud-ops-agent/config.yaml and /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/ to make sure there are no syslog references.
Restarted the Google Cloud Ops Agent:
sudo systemctl restart google-cloud-ops-agent
Checked the rsyslog configuration:
I verified the rsyslog settings in /etc/rsyslog.conf and /etc/rsyslog.d/ to ensure there are no rules forwarding syslog entries to Google Cloud Logging.
Despite these steps, syslog entries such as the following continue to appear in Google Cloud
Jun  5 14:03:01 instance CRON[2061561]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/html/site && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Can anyone provide guidance on how to definitively stop the Google Cloud Ops Agent from logging syslog entries? Any insights or additional steps I might have overlooked would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

The syslog receiver is part of the Ops Agent's built-in configuration. You can follow the first example config here to turn off syslog -- namely, redefine the default_pipeline pipeline's receivers as the empty-array [].

Edit timer expired; by "redefine the default_pipeline pipeline's receivers as the empty-array" I mean, add a new pipeline named default_pipeline to your config, and give it receivers: [].
